# Compare number of files in subfolders

Tags: powershell, comparison, subdirectory

I want to compare the number of files in subfolders of 2 given folders with a PowerShell script, but something isn't working.

I got the paths of the 2 folders through a user input and saved them 
into the variables `$where1` and `$where2`, I also saved the location where the script started of into the variable `$a`. I change to the folders given to get information about the subfolders in there into 2 arrays, one assioated array `$folderArrayX` with the numbers like this `$folderArrayX["subfolder1"]=x` (`x` being the number of child items for subfolder1) and one just with the names of the subfolders for easier comparision. The Code for the first folder given:

```
cd $where1;
$folderArray1 = @();
$folderArray1Keys = @();
Get-Childitem | Select-Object | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
    $ArrayInArray = @{};
    $folderArray1Keys += $_.Name.Trim();
    $ArrayInArray[$_.Name.Trim()] = (Get-ChildItem ./$_).count;
    $folderArray1 += $ArrayInArray;
  }
}
```

I do the same for `$where2` so I get `$folderArray2` and `$folderArray2Keys`.

Now to compare these 2:

```
$r=()  #something to save the returns
Compare-Object $folderArray1Keys $folderArray2Keys -IncludeEqual | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>") {
      $r += ""+$_.InputObect+" only "+$where2+" : "+$folderArray2[$_.InputObject]+" files";
  } elseif ($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=") {
      $r += ""+$_.InputObect+" only "+$where1+" : "+$folderArray1[$_.InputObject]+" files";
  } else {
    if ($folderArray1[$_.InputObject] -gt $folderArray2[$_.InputObject]) {
      $dif = ($folderArray1[$_.InputObject]-$folderArray2[$_.InputObject])
      $r += "on both sides"+$_.InputObject+" has "+$diff+" more files in "+$where1
    } elseif ($folderArray2[$_.InputObject] -gt $folderArray1[$_.InputObject]) {
      $dif = ($folderArray2[$_.InputObject]-$folderArray1[$_.InputObject])
      $r += "on both sides"+$_.InputObject+" has "+$diff+" more files in  "+$where2
    } else {
      $r += ""+$_.InputObject+" is equal on both sides";
    }
  }
}
#Output
$r
cd $a
```

Some how this code doesn't work well. It indicates subfolders as equal which are clearly not (only because they are there and completely ignore the numbers), don't spell out the onesided folders (what I understand the least (it does so for the bothsided folders)) and don't show any numbers. I can't figure out the mistake because assiocated arrays work with PowerShell, I mean a code like this:

```
$k1="key1";
$v1=1;
$k2="key2";
$v2="value2";
$array=@{};
$array[$k1]=$v1;
$array[$k2]=$v2;
$array[$k1]
$array[$k2]
pause
# Exert
# 1
# value2
# Press any key to continue ...
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison routine treats `$folderArray1` and `$folderArray2` as if they were hashtables, but you define them as arrays of hashtables. Basically you're doing this:

```
PS C:\> $h = @{}
PS C:\> $h['foo'] = 42
PS C:\> $a = @()
PS C:\> $a += $h
PS C:\> $a['foo']
PS C:\> $a[0]['foo']
42
```

when you actually want just this:

```
PS C:\> $a = @{}
PS C:\> $a['foo'] = 42
PS C:\> $a['foo']
42
```

Change the code for populating the `$folderArray` variables to this:

```psh
$folderArray = @{}
Get-Childitem | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {
  $folderArray[$_.Name] = @(Get-ChildItem $_.FullName).Count
}
```

and the `Compare-Object` statement to this:

```psh
Compare-Object @($folderArray1.Keys) @($folderArray2.Keys) -IncludeEqual | ...
```

and the problem should disappear.

Comment: It worked, still the method of putting the Arraykeys in an array of their own worked better. This code: $a=@{};
$a["k1"]="v1";
$a["k2"]="v2";
$b=@{};
$b["k2"]="v2";
$b["k3"]="v3";
Compare-Object $a.Keys $b.Keys -IncludeEqual; will produce this output: InputObject {k3, k2} {k2, k1};  SideIndicator  => <=, it just shows that the keys are different. Duh

Comment: @user3284214 The key collections must be turned into arrays. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but my code works good now. One last question: You use $_.Name for the Keys but $_.FullName, is there difference? It seems to work for me with just using $_.Name.

Comment: Because you `cd` into the directory. The difference between `Name` and `FullName` will become obvious if you take a look at the output of `Get-ChildItem | select Name, FullName`.

Comment: Ok thanks, yes I see the difference (absolute Path vs  only the File/SubFolder-Name). But for what that be good other than a choice of style? I mean there is no File with no name, is there?

Comment: Using `FullName` is more robust, because it's an absolute path and doesn't rely on the the enumerated directory being the working directory. Imagine you don't do `cd $where1` and instead run `Get-ChildItem $where1`. With `$_.FullName` the rest of your code will still work. With `$_.Name` you'd have to adjust that part as well.